# VBA to click HTML Input Radio button

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

i would like a vba code to go to this url "http://www.anbima.com.br/ima/ima.asp", then click on the "IRF-M" button, then click on the "Consultar" button.

I've tried this but failed miserably:

```
'inserir website com os valores a serem buscados
sitedv01 = "http://www.anbima.com.br/ima/ima.asp"

'busca no site
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate sitedv01

'espera o carregamento
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set tags = IE.document.getElementsByValue("irf-m")
For Each tagx In tags
    If tagx.src = "http://www.bmf.com.br/bmfbovespa/images/comum/mais.gif" Then
        tagx.Click
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below approach. The script will first click on `IRF-M` and then `Consultar`. However, when the both click are successfully initiated then you will see a new window with the required data you are after.

```
Sub Get_Data()

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://www.anbima.com.br/ima/ima.asp"
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.querySelector("input[value='irf-m']").Click
        .document.querySelector("img[name='Consultar']").Click
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Now, i would like to copy the entire new page, with the required data to then paste on my worksheet and work with the numbers.

Can you help me on that?

I've tried:

        IE.execWB 17, 0
        IE.execWB 12, 0

but it copied the page #1, the original one and not the new one with the data.

Comment: First check it out [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? You can always open a new thread to ask a new question.